# Devise sessions for multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I am building an app with two pretty separate models both using devise for auth.  Once you sign in as a house, then each individual in the house can sign in as a resident of that house.  Everything is working fine except that when i log out of a resident session using

```
destroy_resident_session
```

the only problem with this is that it also kills the house session since it calls

```
Devise::SessionsController#destroy
```

I have tried to create a custom session for residents, here is my code below:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    redirect_path = after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
    signed_out = sign_out(resident)
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out && is_navigational_format?

    # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
    # support returning empty response on GET request
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { head :no_content }
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to redirect_path }
    end
  end
end
```

This gives an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `resident'
```

I may be misunderstanding the method logic but it seems like i want to change the following line in the devise sessions controller:

```
signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
```

Since I do not want to sign out of all scopes, only the resident scope.

**Solved**

All I had to do was set

```
 config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
```

in

```
config/devise.rb
```

And also, had to remember to restart my server :)

Comment: You rock! Was struggling with the same problem. This option really should be mentioned in the "Configuring multiple models" of the README. :) BTW-You should formally answer this question, then accept your own answer.

Comment: I second it: you should add your solution as an answer to this question, then accept that answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

This should be marked as the answer.  You did not post it but I had the same issue and that was the solution so I am posting it for the community

**config/devise.rb**

```
 config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
```